# xamarin forms button text wrap to 2 lines

Tags: xamarin.forms

Above code works fine but for the below code the button should show in single row but it wraps to 2 rows.

```
<Frame CornerRadius="10"  Grid.Row="1"
OutlineColor="#FF00BBEE"  Margin="2,2"
Padding="0">
    <StackLayout Padding="0">
        <Grid Padding="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Large" Text="   B.Sc(Physician Assistant)" HorizontalOptions="Start"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" Text="   Duration:3 Years + 1 Year Internship" HorizontalOptions="Start"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontAttributes="Italic"></Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="2" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" Text="   Eligibility: +2 Pass with Biology as one subject" HorizontalOptions="Start"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
            <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                <Button HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Apply Now"   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>                  
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is Above code? According to your code, you mean that there are four RowDefinitions in Grid, the Label and Button should have same height?

For Grid's RowDefinitions, **default value of the RowDefinition.Height property is ***. So every RowDefinition has same height, but you add **VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"** for every Label and Button, so this property will change height to adapt view's content.

If I delete **VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"**, you can see every RowDefinition have the same height.

```
<Frame
            Margin="2.2"
            Padding="0"
            CornerRadius="10"
            OutlineColor="#FF00BBEE">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    BackgroundColor="Red"
                    FontSize="Large"
                    Text="   B.Sc(Physician Assistant)"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    />
                <Label
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    BackgroundColor="Aquamarine"
                    Text="   Duration:3 Years + 1 Year Internship"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    />
                <Label
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    BackgroundColor="Beige"
                    Text="   Eligibility: +2 Pass with Biology as one subject"
                    TextColor="Black"
                     />

                <Button Grid.Row="3" Text="Apply Now" BackgroundColor="BlueViolet" />

            </Grid>

        </Frame>
```

[image]